# Error when updating the information of a extension on an existing message on Microsoft Graph using PHP SDK and PostMan

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, postman, microsoft-graph-sdks

Basically, I follow the steps to configure the Microsoft graph and I'm using the postman and Microsoft Graph PHP SDK
Im running this request to create the message.
POST -> https://graph.microsoft.com/1.0/me/messages
Payload :

```php
[
    'body' => [
        'contentType' => 'Text',
        'content' => 'The new cafeteria is open.',
    ],
    'toRecipients' => [
        [
            'emailAddress' => [
                'address' => 'example@email.com',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    "from" => [
        "emailAddress" => [
            "name" => "Issue j",
            "address" => "example@email.com"
        ]
    ]
]
```

After that im running a PATCH Request, to update the data of an extension already created, this is the get request for the extension, just to confirm you guys, that extension exists and the IDS, are correct and attributes are ok.
GET -> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions
Payload :

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions(id,description)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "ext13c4xvul_EmailTags",
            "description": null,
            "targetTypes": [
                "Message"
            ],
            "status": "Available",
            "owner": "IM APP ID",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "testasdsad",
                    "type": "String"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I PATCH the information of my extension on my existing message
PATCH -> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/
Payload

```json
{"ext13c4xvul_EmailTags":{"testasdsad":"OI2"}}
```

This PATCH only works on Microsoft Graph Explorer, and on the GRAPH SDK PHP and POSTMAN its not working.
I also do the experience of using the token (from explorer) directly on my app, and works perfectly, The scopes and permissions are the same

Im getting this error on both sides PHP SDK and postman

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBodyRead",
        "message": "A type named 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-12-30T14:43:34",
            "request-id": "1cfcfb94-179a-4572-b66f-47d1e2178d20",
            "client-request-id": "1cfcfb94-179a-4572-b66f-47d1e2178d20"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Additive updates to the extension can only be made when the extension is in the InDevelopment or Available status.

The update applies to all the resources that are included in the targetTypes property of the extension. These resources are among the supporting resource types.

For delegated flows, the signed-in user can update a schema extension as long as the owner property of the extension is set to the appId of an application the signed-in user owns. That application can be the one that initially created the extension or some other application owned by the signed-in user.

Follow documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to update Schema Extensions.